# Is it true that in any boolean algebra $x\oplus0 = x$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was wondering about this question.

Logically, I would like to say that in every boolean algebra that is true.

Because: $x\oplus0=x·0'+x'·0 = x·0'$.

And in the binary boolean algebra that is correct as: $0'=1 \rightarrow x·0'=x·1=x$

But is that true for ANY of it?

I would love some insight from you, thank you!

Comment: What has this got to do with group theory?

Comment: @Shaun I figured because generally the members of the boolean algebra have to be a part of a certain group $B$, which can contain more than 2 members.

Comment: By 'group,' do you mean 'set’?

Comment: @William Yes, that is possibly true. I'm not studying in English, and we have the same name for both of these, I'll make an edit. I would appreciate any insight regarding the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [axioms of a boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)), we have
$$\lnot0=\lnot0\lor0=1$$
and
$$x\land0=0\land x=0\land(0\lor x)=0,$$
so if $x\oplus y$ is defined as $(x\land\lnot y)\lor(\lnot x\land y)$, then we have $$x\oplus0=(x\land\lnot 0)\lor(\lnot x\land 0)=(x\land1)\lor0=x.$$